# Regex to split string

Tags: java, regex, split

I have this code which prints:

```
[( ?Random = <http://www.semanticweb.org/vassilis/ontologies/2013/5/Test#Hello> ), ( ?Random = <http://www.semanticweb.org/vassilis/ontologies/2013/5/Test#Bye> )]
```

I tried to split at [#] but it didnt work.

What should i put in split so that I can get as a result the part after # only: Hello, Bye

```
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
                     QueryExecution qe= QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
                    ResultSet resultset = qe.execSelect();
                    ResultSet results = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(resultset); 
                    final ResultSet results2 = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(results);


                    System.out.println( "== Available Options ==" );
                    ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);



    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String inputs;
    inputs = input.next();
    final String[] indices = inputs.split("\\s*,\\s*");

    final List<QuerySolution> selectedSolutions = new ArrayList<QuerySolution>(
            indices.length) {
        {
            final List<QuerySolution> solutions = ResultSetFormatter
                    .toList(results2);
            for (final String index : indices) {
                add(solutions.get(Integer.valueOf(index)));
            }
        }
    };

    System.out.println(selectedSolutions);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only want to extract "Hello" and "Bye" from your input String through regex.

In which case, I would just use iterative matching of whatever's in between `#` and `>`, as such:

```
// To clarify, this String is just an example
// Use yourScannerInstance.nextLine to get the real data
String input = "[( ?Random = <http://www.semanticweb.org/vassilis/ontologies/2013/5/Test#Hello> ), "
                + "( ?Random = <http://www.semanticweb.org/vassilis/ontologies/2013/5/Test#Bye> )]";
// Pattern improved by Brian
// was: #(.+?)>
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#([^>]+)>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
// To clarify, printing the String out is just for testing purpose
// Add "m.group(1)" to a Collection<String> to use it in further code
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
Bye
```

Comment: +1, beat me to it, but use `"#([^>]+)>"`, it can be much faster than using reluctant quantifiers.

Comment: @Brian thanks for the improvement tip and fair play! Will edit my answer now.

Comment: I want the output to be: Hello, Bye      and if i use this I cant get results, because the string input = "..." you wrote is not always the same and changes depending on user input. (example type 1,2 and get different results from 3,4). However I always need to get the same part between # and >

Comment: @user2598911 I think you actually can. My `String input` is just an example. Replace it with `input.nextLine()` (wherein this second instance of `input`is the instance of your `Scanner`) and you should be ok. - Edit: also, instead of printing it out, you can add it to a `Collection<String>` such as an `ArrayList<String>`, etc. and use it in the code after.

Comment: Even with input.nextLine as your input it still wont show results. With my query I get 4 results similar to the one I wrote in a list. I then type 1, 2 to get the first one and the second one. I get them with the code above. All i need is modify their format as shown above in the example. Your code wont even show the results 1,2 in any form

Comment: ok worked it out. thanks but how could i pass m from matcher to an arraylist? with arrlist.add?

Comment: @user2598911 sorry went to the gym. Yes, with `yourArrayListInstance.add(matcher.group(1))` in this instance.

Comment: for some reason when i do:  while (m.find()) {
        ArrayList.add(m.group());
     }       I get [#Hello,#Bye] and if I do m.group(1) I get [Hello,Bye] . I want to get only Hello, Bye (no [] or #)

Comment: You're probably printing the `ArrayList` instead of each of its elements - I'd advise to take a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Using `m.group()` will add the whole match; as said you want `m.group(1)` which will add what's between `#` and `>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
String[] str= your_orginal_String.split(",");
```

Then you can take the parts after # as follows

```
String[] s=new String[2];
int j=0;
for(String i:str){
    s[j]=i.split("#",2)[1];
    j++;
}
```

You may need some formatting. for resulting `String[] s` as follows

```
    String str = "[( ?Random = <http://www.semanticweb.org/vassilis
                   /ontologies/2013/5/Test#Hello> ), ( ?Random = 
            <http://www.semanticweb.org/vassilis/ontologies/2013/5/Test#Bye> )]";
    String[] arr = str.split(",");
    String[] subArr = new String[arr.length];
    int j = 0;
    for (String i : arr) {
        subArr[j] = i.split("#", 2)[1].replaceAll("\\>|\\)|\\]", "");
        j++;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subArr));
```

Out put:

```
  [Hello , Bye ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the regular expression:

```
(?<=#)([^#>]+)
```

e.g.:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("(?<=#)([^#>]+)");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "[( ?A = <http://www.semanticweb.org/vassilis/ontologies/2013/5/Test#Hello> ), ( ?A = <http://www.semanticweb.org/vassilis/ontologies/2013/5/Test#World> )]";
    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
World
```