# Matcher and regex

Tags: java, regex

I have this string newstr that I want to parse:

```
[( ?A = <http://www.semanticweb.org/vassilis/ontologies/2013/5/Test#Hello> ), ( ?A = <http://www.semanticweb.org/vassilis/ontologies/2013/5/Test#World> )]
```

With the code shown below I get this as result:

```
[#Hello>, #World>]
```

What should I change to get:

```
Hello, World
```

Code:

```
List<String> strlist = new ArrayList<String>() ;

                  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#([^>]+)>");
                   Matcher m = p.matcher(newstr);


                   while (m.find()) {
                       strto.add(m.group());
                    }



    System.out.println(strtogams);
   String[] strto2 = strto.toArray(new String[20]) ;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855209/regex-to-split-string

Comment: Change `m.group()` to `m.group(1)`.

Comment: Why did you use `m.group()` when the answer you accepted in your other question has `m.group(1)`?

Comment: -1: You've already asked almost this exact question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Java can do look behind assertions, maybe this:

```
 (?<=\#)[^>]+
```

P.s. - I didn't look at the other question (should have, but ..)